# Create a 3D face from the Shroud of Turin

Tags: image-processing, image3d

There is an image of the [Shroud of Turin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shroud_of_Turin):

[image]

How to recreate Jesus's face from this image?

And how to create a 3D face of Jesus Christ,  by using the shroud of Turin?

I tried:

> ImageAdjust @ ColorNegate[ image ]

[image]

Thank you in advance to any one who may be able to give me some ideas

Comment: Just apply a texture to the face of Brian

Comment: @Dr.belisarius Who is Brian?  :))

Answer (score 6):

Importing:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMZN4.jpg"];
```

Inverting the colors and stretching the range:

```
improved = img // ColorNegate // ImageAdjust
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Preparing a mask to remove some of the artefacts:

```
mask = Dilation[Binarize[improved, .45], DiskMatrix[3]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Trying to remove the artefacts:

```
inp = Inpaint[improved, mask]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Plot the result (blurring the image data a bit to get rid of the high frequency noise):

```
ListPlot3D[
  ImageData[
    ColorConvert[inp // Blur[#, 10] &, "Grayscale"]
  ],
  Boxed -> False, Mesh -> None, Axes -> False
]
```

[image]

Comment: `Inpaint[ heresy, Method -> "EnhanceForgeries"]`

Comment: Not bad, but I had expected something like [this](https://shroudofturin.files.wordpress.com/2011/03/image77.png)  :)

Comment: @vito they probably had a better picture than the one you provided.

Answer (score 2):

Do you still need some help with this? I have some of the highest resolution images of the shroud ever taken and have created some very good 3D images. I can show you how to do it and provide some software that does this automatically. You can adjust the parameters to refine the results or change settings prior to rendering the image. My E-Mail address is djleejay85@googlemail.com .. Or you can add me on my Facebook account https://www.facebook.com/lee.jones.520357 . Kind reguards. Lee